# Unable to upload image in MEAN-stack app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mean-stack

So I have a mean stack app. At a user's profile page I want them to be able to upload an image.

Now, I start by selecting it in the template, then through the component it reaches the service file where I make a POST request with formData. In the back-end I used *Multer* middleware to handle the upload, but something goes wrong here. The following is my code on the back-end.

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: '../public/uploads/' });

router.post('/uploadProfilePicture/:userId', upload.single('avatar'), function(req, res){
    console.log('entered');
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).json({
        msg: 'guuud'
    })
});
```

I mostly just want to check if I reach the back-end. The console gives me the following error:

> POST /user/uploadProfilePicture/5aaf1b7c18f2aa3d88e3b59e 500 16.382 ms
>   - 1711

There's no console log of *entered* and neither of the other ones. Something goes wrong between the service and the back-end, but I have absolutely no idea.

Here are the service and other files used for this upload.

**Service.component.ts**

```
postFile(fileToUpload: File, userId) {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        console.log(fileToUpload);
        formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
        console.log(formData);

        return this.http.post("http://localhost:3200/user/uploadProfilePicture/" + userId, formData)
            .map(() => { return true; })
            .catch((e) => this.handleError(e));
    }
```

**Here is the page + the results of the console.logs in the service file**

[image]

**profile.component.ts**

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList){
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    this.uploadFileToActivity();
}

uploadFileToActivity() {
    this.userService.postFile(this.fileToUpload, localStorage.getItem('userId')).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**profile.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 profilePicSection">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file">Choose File</label>
            <input type="file"
                   id="file"
                   (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Edit: The error my server console gives me:**

```
Error: Unexpected field
    at makeError (C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\test\moviemeter\node_modules\multer\lib\make-error.js:12:13)
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\test\moviemeter\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\test\moviemeter\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\test\moviemeter\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\test\moviemeter\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\test\moviemeter\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
    at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at HeaderParser._finish (C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\test\moviemeter\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\test\moviemeter\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)
    at SBMH.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at SBMH._sbmh_feed (C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\test\moviemeter\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:159:14)
    at SBMH.push (C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\test\moviemeter\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:56:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\test\moviemeter\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:46:19)
    at Dicer._oninfo (C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\test\moviemeter\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:197:25)
```

Comment: your file  may upload on server but it may not add an extension

Comment: var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

Comment: you should use above snippet to upload a file

Comment: `/user/uploadProfilePicture` is the path or `/uploadProfilePicture` ?

Comment: It's /user/uploadProfilePicture. It's in a router file.

Comment: I'll try out the suggestion you just made and tell you how it goes.

Comment: I tried it, but still not working. My server console gives me an error. I'll add it to the original post.

Comment: Is it possible that I need to make adjustments to my server request in my service file?

Comment: The file is appended to the formData object as `fileKey`, but multer expects `avatar`. Not sure if that's what causes the 500 error though. But worth a try.

Comment: I can't kiss you, but if I could I would. Thanks a lot Chris. I changed it to fileKey and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for video type files and it works fine, Hope it helps you

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {

            var fileDest = path.join('../uploads/');
            if (!fs.existsSync(fileDest)) {
                mkdirp(fileDest, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        logger.error(err);
                        callback(err, false);
                    } else {
                        callback(null, '../uploads');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                callback(null, '../uploads/');
            }

    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[1]);
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {

        // To reject this file pass `false`, like so:
        var sw = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < config.videoMimeTypes.length; i++) {
            if (file.mimetype === config.videoMimeTypes[i]) {
                sw = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (sw === 0) {
            logger.error('Not allowed file type sent');
            // return callback(new Error('Only video files are allowed!'));
            return callback('Only video files are allowed!', false);
        }

        // To accept the file pass `true`, like so:
        callback(null, true);

    },
    limits: {
        fileSize: config.maxUploadSize
    }
});

app.post('/upload', upload.any(), router.uploader);
```